# Where to place php code snippets in Drupal?

Tags: emails

Whereabouts are you meant to place a snippet of php code? I am guessing the root of site? Don't you need to have something point to it?

I am wanting to place this snippet I found to encode email http://shamsphp.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/how-to-encode-email-address.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a theme-based snippet, you can put that in your `/sites/all/themes/THEME/template.php` file at the end, or even one of the `.tpl.php` files.  The preferred method for stuff like this is to keep it centralized and easy to manage/fix/alter in the future.

At the bottom of that file just paste the code in and reload your cache.  To take advantage of it in specific spots, you can utilize Drupal's theme preprocess and form_alter hook functions.

Comment: thanks and so i can call it anything?

Comment: Yep but I would advise taking it and putting the whole thing inside one of the hooks in template.php (they are all named as such: `THEME_preprocess_page()`, `THEME_form_alter()`, `THEME_preprocess_html()`, etc).  Whichever is the lowest level to what you want to alter (so if it's supposed to fixed e-mail addresses that show up in `comments`, you can use the `THEME_preprocess_comment()` and just make sure to invoke it by putting `email_function();` at the end of the hook function you choose.

Comment: It is actually for email field in a page view but I understand what you are saying, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should place this helper function in your custom module, so once the module get enabled the you can call this function anywhere across drupal environment.

Comment: yeah I was gonna suggest this but then realized...if he's asking what to do with PHP code in general, a module may be a ways off lol +1 for mind reading though.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I am not sure how you mean exactly because I haven't made a custom module.

Comment: I am a SHE btw but nm most think i am a HE

Comment: @CharlieBunt for future reference for building a module https://drupal.org/node/1074362 post may help you.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've had a quick read through of the start of that and really looking forward to studying it all the way through.